# sitecore xpath query that excludes cloned items

Tags: xpath, content-management-system, sitecore

I have a multilist field inside of an item template that includes an XPath query to filter the item options.

```
query:/sitecore/content/mysite/Home//*[@@templatename='MytemplateName']
```

this works fine, but there are cloned items under `/sitecore/content/mysite/Home` which show up twice since there are two actual items in the content tree,

how can I alter this query to exclude duplicates?

Comment: Is `@@` a typo or the source of the 'bug' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the value of **`__Source`** field is empty.

In this field **Sitecore** stores information about the original item for cloned items, so this field will be not empty for all the cloned items and they will be omitted in the results:

```
query:/sitecore/content/mysite/Home//*[@@templatename='MytemplateName' and @__source='']
```

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with Sitecore, but why do you prefix `templatename` (I guess it's an attribute) with a double `@@`, but do not write  `@@_source`?

Comment: This is not the standard xpath parser, it is Sitecore xpath which is slightly different. Single `@` character is used for Sitecore fields (`@__source`), while `@@` is used for item properties (`@@templatename`).